# How can I reconstruct session from pcap file?

Tags: log-files, session, pcap

I am trying to extract session level (flow level) information from my pcap trace file.

I want to generate the following data for each line of session (flow):

```
 Flow_num, IP_Src, IP_Dst, Flow_start_time, Flow_Duration, Flow_type (video/image/text/...), Protocol, Flow_size
```

Answer (score 1):

Use tcpdump to display pcap file then use a script to filter/calculate the output. Check out this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/38626/how-can-i-read-pcap-files-in-a-friendly-format) about tcpdump and pcap.